# outlook rule to move email when certaing group is CC

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I had the rule to move an incoming email when is sent to this group, but sometimes they add the group as CC, and I couldn't find a way to choose this condition.

Is there a way to solve this with rules or should I investigate VBA code?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the existed VBA codes in this article could help [How to Auto Move the Emails with Specific CC Recipients in Outlook](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/auto-move-email-specific-cc-recipients/).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.